# Error DbContext in 1:1 reference call view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have 2 classes, and try to use the reference in view of a class to another class gives the error:

The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Class "CLIENTE"

```
public class Cliente : IEntidadeBase
{
  [Key]
  [Display(Name = "Cód. de Cliente")]
  public int ClienteID { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Cód. de Pessoa")]
  public int PessoaID { get; set; }
  public string Matriz { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Limite de crédito")]
  public decimal LimiteCredito { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("PessoaID")]
  public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

Class "PESSOA"

```
public class Pessoa : IEntidadeBase
{
  [Key]
  public int PessoaID { get; set; }
  public int? EmpresaIDVinc { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Matrícula")]
  public string Matricula { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Nome")]
  [Obrigatorio]
  public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Controller View change:

```
[Authorize]
[ControleDeAcesso(TipoAcao.Normal)]
public ActionResult Detalhar(int id)        
{
    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        Cliente cliente = db.Cliente.Find(id);
        var retorno = FlexGestor.Helpers.EntidadeBaseExt.ValidarRegistro(cliente, TipoAcao.Visualizar);
        if (retorno != "")
        {
            TempData["MsgRetornoError"] = retorno;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(cliente);
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
@model FlexGestor.Models.Cliente

@Html.TituloPagina("Visualizando Cliente")


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);

    <div class="linha left">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClienteID)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Pessoa.Nome) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Pessoa.Nome)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pessoa.Nome, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LimiteCredito) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LimiteCredito)<br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LimiteCredito, new { style = "width:250px;" })<br />

        @Html.BotaoTelaDetalhar()        
    </div>    
}

<div class="linha rodape"></div>
```

Comment: where is the issue... in the view? do you have the view's code. I personally would try moving the Cliente out of the using block and then checking if it is null before returning to the view or you might get issues in the view

Comment: @Adween add to code view...the problem is that I need to access the "PESSOA" class from the class "CLIENTE"

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on `Cliente cliente = db.Cliente.Find(id);` after it has executed is `cliente.pessoa` null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this will fix your issue but try changing to this and see if it helps

```
[Authorize]
[ControleDeAcesso(TipoAcao.Normal)]
public ActionResult Detalhar(int id)        
{
    Cliente cliente = null;
    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        cliente = db.Cliente.Find(id);
        var retorno = FlexGestor.Helpers.EntidadeBaseExt.ValidarRegistro(cliente, TipoAcao.Visualizar);
        if (retorno != "")
        {
            TempData["MsgRetornoError"] = retorno;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

    if(cliente != null && cliente.pessoa != null)
    {
        return View(cliente);
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else here as the view does not have required stuff
    }
}
```